# Optimization algorithm (dog-leg trust-region) in Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, scipy, minimization

I'm trying to solve a set of nonlinear equations using the dog-leg trust-region algorithm in Matlab and Python.

In Matlab there is [fsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) where this algorithm is the default, whereas for Python we specify 'dogleg' in [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). I won't need to specify a Jacobian or Hessian for the Matlab whereas Python needs either one to solve the problem.

I don't have the Jacobian/Hessian so is there a way around this issue for Python? Or is there another function that performs the equivalent of Matlab's dog-leg method in `fsolve`?

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of scipy there is the [approx_fprime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html#scipy.optimize.approx_fprime) function. It computes a numerical approximation of the jacobian of function `f` at position `xk` using the foward step finite difference. It returns an ndarray with the partial derivate of `f` at positions `xk`.

If you can't upgrade your version of scipy, you can always copy the implementation from [scipy's source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L616-L688).

---

Edit:

`scipy.optimize.minimize` calls `approx_fprime` internally if the input `jac=False`. So in your case, it should be enough to do the following:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args, method='dogleg', jac=False)
```

---

Edit

`scipy` does not seem to handle the `jac=False` condition properly so it is necessary to build a callable `jac` using `approx_fprime` as follows

```
jac = lambda x,*args: scipy.optimize.approx_fprime(x,fun,epsilon,*args)
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args, method='dogleg', jac=jac)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you for making me notice. I edited my answer and also added a part stating that minimize calls `approx_fprime` internally if `jac=False`

Comment: I get an error when I specify `jac=False`: `ValueError: Jacobian is required for dogleg minimization`.

Comment: It seems like an error in scipy's handling of the [numeric estimation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L411-L416). The error persists in current versions of scipy so it seems like it is necessary to place a bug ticket or something else. To solve your specific problem, you will have to build a callable `jac` using a `approx_fprime`. I have edited my answer accordingly.